# Random function in Racket (more complex)

Tags: function, random, racket

I know the basics about random function in Racket but I am trying to do something more difficult.

I am trying to develop a random function that gives randomly an element of a list I give to the function as parameter. For example:

```
‘(a h j l u) -> Output: h

‘(w t) -> Output: w

‘(l u t n) -> Output: t
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, assuming a non-empty list and using built-in procedures:

```
(define (pick-random lst)
  (first (shuffle lst)))
```

For example:

```
(pick-random '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A way would be to first get the length of the list, do `(random len)` to get a number `[0,len-1]` and use that with `list-ref` to get the element.